# C++ Error: ISO C++ Forbids Comparison Between Pointer and Integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, shutdown, dev-c++

I am a beginner C++ Programmer With Very little knowledge about C++. I Have Been Creating a Program on The IDE and Compiler: Dev-C++ 5.6.3. I have run into this error:  ISO C++ Forbids Comparison Between Pointer and Integer [-fpermissive]. I don't know what it means.

Comment: @drescherjm, `goto` can be a good idea in certain situations, but I'd wager never a good idea for a beginner.

Comment: The only good use I've found for `goto` is error recovery in certain arcane situations. Like being on a platform without exception handling.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, True, the only good use I've seen in C has been for error handling, too. I'm not cutting out the possibility that it does have a genuinely good use somewhere else.

Comment: That said, the code referenced by `Lobby`, `Shut2`, and `Error` is not posted, so there's no way to know what's going on here. Another big problem is the mixing of `<iostream>` (`cout`) and `<stdio.h>` (`scanf`, `getch`) code. This can have all kinds of odd side effects because those two I/O libraries don't always keep in sync with each other.

Comment: This program looks like a direct translation from gwbasic.  C++ has much better ways of controlling program flow than using `goto` everywhere.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, AFAIK, they're synced by default until you call `sync_with_stdio(false)`. Please correct me if this is wrong. (Not that I recommend mixing the two anyway.)

Comment: How about a cin instead of scanf()?

Comment: There's also the little problem that `%c` for `scanf` expects a `char *`, not a `int *`.

Comment: Of all the problems in this code,  everybody jumps on `goto` ...

Comment: @chris: I hadn't seen that function before. (Learned the language on the kind of compilers that would always say "Templates and exception handling are not supported".) I guess it was standardized by C++98 or so?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, I guess so seeing as how cppreference has no *since C++xx* remark. I've never used it, so I'm not familiar with it beyond that one point.

Comment: @chris I just remember having problems with random output reordering when mixing the calls, but again this was back in the early 90's when C standard libraries would do nothing to integrate with C++ or other languages' libraries, and having a "native" C++ compiler (as opposed to `cfront`) was the new thing. Nice of them to fix the problem for good.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, I keep hearing of these magical times and while it would be cool to experience them, I keep being reassured that not having been around at that time is a good thing.

Comment: @chris I don't miss the days of strangeness like "loops cannot be used in inline functions" (because they cannot be reduced to expressions, unlike how `if` statements can be replaced with ternary operators and successive statements can be turned into a long series of `,`-delimited expressions).

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, Funny you should mention that because it re-emerged with `constexpr` functions (except recursion) until C++14 set us straight.

Answer (score 7):

`"Y"`, `"y"`, `"n"`, and `"N"` are C-style strings, which are null-terminated character arrays.  When attempting to compare them, they degenerate to pointers to `const char`.  On the other hand, `inputy` is declared as `int`.  This is the origin of your comparison between pointer and integer errors.

To fix the issue, compare `inputy` against characters instead of strings: `'Y'`, `'y'`, `'n'`, and `'N'` (note the single quotes, rather than double quotes).

Comment: Also a change needs to be made, either `inputy` be a `char`, or `scanf("%c"` not be used

Answer (score 2):

You have another problem. You've declared `int inputy;` but you are trying to read a **character** by doing `scanf("%c", &inputy);`. The format string `%c` does not match the data type of `&inputy`. If you want to read a character you should use the correct type for the input variable:

```
char inputy;

scanf("%c", &inputy);
```

Comment: Ah yes, the confusion caused by the fact that so many "character" functions in C use `int` to pass or return the character.

Comment: Come to think of it, if running on a little-endian platform, and if the memory used by `inputy` was initialized to `0` by some means, then correct behavior will be observed even though the pointer is pointing to the wrong type (because the byte the pointer points to is the lowest-order byte of the `int`). Definitely "undefined behavior" as far as the language is concerned.